# Cocoa class method signature problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad, function, delegates

I have a class method but when in header file, it doesn´t want to compile:"expected a type"

```
+(void)addCommentSectionIntoMonitoringReport:(NSString*)DBCommentName:(NSString*)keyName:(NSManagedObject*)outerObjectToDB:(NSDictionary *)monitoring_report;
```

but when I add:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

it works fine. Can you tell me why? What does AppDelegate has to do with NSManagedObject type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you #importing `<CoreData/CoreData.h>` in your .h?

Answer (score 1):

First, your method is a class method (+ sign).

Second, your method signature requires knowledge of NSManagedObject and NSDictionary.

Since those are the only elements requiring "external" knowledge, I'd wager AppDelegate.h contains imports of one of these.

I just tested your method by pasting it into one of my classes that imports headers that import CoreData. It builds fine, except it's marked as "unimplemented" ;)